# How to place new marker google maps in PHP?

Tags: php, google-maps, google-app-engine

I learn using google maps for basic. And want create a simple application with marker to show longitude, latitude.
What I should use Google maps API v3 ?. Can give me refrences or tutorial ?.
Best regards, Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

[Google Maps JavaScript API v3](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/) is a good option for PHP sites.  You should probably begin with the [Introduction](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial) and [Simple Example](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/map-simple).  Enjoy!